# How can I set an element HTML to the value of a variable with jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am using the following code and it sets the value of the 2nd line correctly. When I use the debugger I can see that typeSelected HAS a text value I expect:

```
            var typeSelected      = $("#dialogType :selected").text();
            parent.find(".refType").html('aa');
```

When I replace it with:

```
            var typeSelected      = $("#dialogType :selected").text();
            parent.find(".refType").html(typeSelected);
```

Then the 2nd line doesn't get set to anything.

Is it wrong just for me to put .html(typeSelected) ?

Comment: Try `console.log(typeSelected)`, what does it output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What kind of element is `"#dialogType"`?

Looking at `":selected"` I think you should use `.val()` instead of `.text()` to get the correct value.

Answer (score 1):

```
var typeSelected = $("#dialogType").val();
parent.find(".refType").html(typeSelected);
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what type of element typeSelected is, but if it has a value, try:

```
var typeSelected = $("#dialogType").val();
```

`.text()` works great on elements with a textnode, such as `<p>, <a>` etc, while `.val()` is for values, such as `<input>` for example.